# How do I add dates in Emacs using Emacs Lisp?

Tags: datetime, emacs, elisp

I want to use Emacs Lisp to perform math operations like add and difference on dates and times.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The short answer is: read the [System Interface section](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/System-Interface.html#System-Interface) of the elisp info manual.  More specifically, the time sections:

- [Time of day](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Time-of-Day.html#Time-of-Day)
- [Time conversion](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Time-Conversion.html#Time-Conversion)
- [Time parsing](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Time-Parsing.html#Time-Parsing)
- [Time calculations](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Time-Calculations.html#Time-Calculations)

The longer answer:

Emacs can work with time values as strings, floats, or a tuple of two or three integers.  E.g. call some functions in the `*scratch*`buffer:

```
(current-time)
(19689 59702 984160)
(current-time-string)
"Sun Nov 21 20:54:22 2010"
(current-time-zone)
(-25200 "MST")
(float-time)
1290398079.965001
```

Let's some conversions:

```
(decode-time (current-time))
(33 7 21 21 11 2010 0 nil -25200)
(decode-time) ; (current-time) by default
(51 7 21 21 11 2010 0 nil -25200)

(let ((seconds 36)
      (minutes 10)
      (hour 21)
      (day 21)
      (month 11)
      (year 2010))
  (encode-time seconds minutes hour day month year))
(19689 60732)

(format-time-string "%A %e %B" (current-time))
"Sunday 21 November"

(seconds-to-time 23)
(0 23 0)

(time-to-seconds (current-time))
1290399309.598342

(time-to-days (current-time))
734097
```

Finally, to answer your question:

```
(time-add (current-time) (seconds-to-time 23))
(19689 60954 497526)

(time-subtract (current-time) (seconds-to-time 45))
(19689 61001 736330)
```

Comment: I was reading through it but I didn't notice the Time Calculations section, thanks!

Comment: I believe `seconds-to-time` is not needed in your final examples.